# Python Import Error (ModuleNotFoundError) when importing a function from a module that imports a class from another module

Tags: python, importerror

My file structure looks like:

```
/dir/
    main.py
    /src/
        functionsfile.py
        classfile.py
```

The `functionsfile` has a function that uses the class created in the `classfile`. I import that class with

```
from classfile import ClassName
```

(I've also tried importing `*`).

Just testing the function in the `functionsfile` with a `print` statement, it appears to find the class module and use the `ClassName` just fine, but then when I `import` that function from `functionsfile` into the `main.py` script, it gives me the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'classfile'
```

I tried importing the function with both:

```
from functionsfile import function
```

and

```
from functionsfile import *
```

I'm at a loss for why this is happening?

Comment: Why do you have the other files in a separate folder?

Comment: you have a loop in your dependencies: one file importing from another which is importing the current file. If for some reason you can't do without it, you should use local imports in the function that needs it, but most likely, you just need to reorganize your code to avoid this loop.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a loop? main.py imports from functionsfile that imports from classfile. Looks linear to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
from src.classfile import ClassName
```

It would also be better to change your directory structure.

```
/dir
  /src
    /class
       classfile.py
       functionsfile.py
    main.py
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much! I guess when importing the functionsfile, the imported modules that are not on the sys.path need an importing path relative to the final file using the function.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are missing **__init__.py** file. Try importing after adding that in your /src/ folder.

Answer (score 1):

As what Aquarius said you need to create a blank `__init__.py` file inside src folder

And try to import it as

```
from src.classfile import *
```

Inside your `main.py` file

I hope it works for you : D

Comment: I just tried adding __init__.py to both folders.. still have this problem. Didn't think I had to since I have the latest version of python and it's not supposed to be necessary anymore. Anyway, I'm still getting the error :(